# WkWebview is freezing with Angular

Tags: javascript, ios, css, angularjs, wkwebview

### Background

We have a simple **Angular+Bootstrap** app that is running in an external application that uses **WkWebview** to embed our page. The app works fine in Desktop all OS's, Android and Iphone. 
There are not javascript errors or CSS warns.

### Problem

However, **randomly** it freezes running in IPad when we tap a `<a href="#screen2"`. This trigger a change on the `routerProvider` in order to change the screen controller and template.
 It seams like a transparent layer is locking the entire screen. Or that all events (click tab scroll) are locked.

### Weirdness

If we change the orientation to landscape the screen is unlocked. If we turned again to portrait it lock again.

### Additional

We cant change the WkWebview for a newer. We only have control over the webapp. 
We know that WkWebview has several issues related to: Scrolling, focus and Display changes that affect the rendering and causes blank or freeze screen. 
We also are using this script to avoid blank screen on some focus events:

```
(function(){
  try{
      var a=navigator.userAgent;
      if((a.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||a.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS/9')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 9')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 10')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS/10')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){
        var s=document.createElement('style'); 
        if(a.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1) {
            s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}";
        }
        else if(a.indexOf('OS/9')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 9')!=-1) {
            s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}";
        }
        else if(a.indexOf('OS/10')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 10')!=-1) {
            s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}";
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
      }
  } catch(e){}
})();
```

### Question

Any workaround to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There will be two problems as your statement if better share the link for cross-check

1)Angular+bootstrap application issue
check your application os production build or not, the images, css is minified or not and its support DSN or not.

2)WkWebview issue: your checking your web application on Wkwebview the has some memory limitation but that before just check the configuration setting of webview

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration